# Showing the class of all recursive sets is recursively enumerable.

Tags: proof-verification, computability

Correct?

Proof:

Let D = {$A_i$ |$A_i$ is a recursive set$\}$. Take $z \in D$. Thus $z = A_i$ for some  $i\in N$.

Then: $\exists{f}$ such that for any choice of $A_i$ $\in$ D:

$f(x) = 1$ if $x \in A_i$ and $f(x) = \emptyset$ otherwise.

We call each such $f$ an $f_i$ as it gives a decision procedure for $A_i$.

We now show that $D$ has a semi-decision procedure, and therefore is R.E. (recursively enumerable). We define $g$ on $D$ as follows:

$g(x) = 1$ if $f_i(x) = 1$ for some $A_i$ $\in$ D & $g(x)$ = undefined otherwise.

We show that D can under no circumstances be recursive.

Subproof: Suppose D were recursive for a contradiction, symbolized by $\bot$. Then

$\Rightarrow$ D has a decision procedure

$\Rightarrow$ The complement of D, say D`, is recursive (and so has a decision procedure)

$\Rightarrow$ D` $\in$ D (By the definition of D)

$\Rightarrow$ D` = $A_i$ for some $A_i$ $\in$ D.

$\Rightarrow$ But D` $\neq$ $A_i$ for every $A_i$ (by definition of complement of D)

$\Rightarrow$ $\bot$.

END SUBPROOF.

END PROOF.

Comment: The first glaring problem I see is that you treat $D$ as an indexing set and a set of languages at the same time. You take $A \in D$ and $i \in D$ and say $A = A_{i}$. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure that I follow. Are you suggesting I fix the definition of D to something like {$A_i$ | $A_i$ is a set and $A_i$ is recursive}?

Comment: That is a better definition. If you want to stick with your original definition, you want $i \in \mathbb{N}$, not $i \in D$. Note that in this case, $\mathbb{N}$ is an indexing set.

Comment: I think other than that, your proof looks good to me.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean, exactly, by "the class of all recursive sets is recursively enumerable".  Can you please state your definition of that? There are several possibilities, but in most of them the class of computable sets would not be r.e.

Comment: In your proof, you say "$g(x) = 1$ if $f_i = 1$ for some $i \in D$. But there is no $i$ in $D$; $D$ contains only sets.

Comment: @CarlMummert: The one Rogers has is different than I was thinking about it. I was thinking that a recursive set is one which has a decision procedure, and a recursively enumerable set / class is one which has a semi-decision procedure, i.e. a characteristic function which can yield "Yes" but not "no". Intuitively these sets can be indexed if they are enumerable at all. Is there something wrong about this approach to the proof?

Comment: @CarlMummert: So, avoiding the notation, in Rogers' book on page 73, he has: "A class C of recursively enumerable sets is a *recursively enumerable class* if an effective procedure exists which enumerates at least one r.e. index for every member of C." These r.e. indexes are just Godel numbers, i.e. natural numbers assigned to r.e. sets. Is this satisfactory?

Comment: So the question is to prove that there is an r.e. sequence $a(i)$ such that (1) for all $i$, $W_{a(i)}$ is a computable set and (2) for every computable set $C$ there is an $i$ such that $C = W_{a(i)}$. Is that correct? Can there be distinct $i,j$ with $W_{a(i)} = W_{a(j)}$?

Comment: He phrases the problem as I have above, but your notation corresponds to his.

Comment: @CarlMummert: Do you have a specific counterexample to offer here? Otherwise, I don't see how my proof is erroneous. Is it *necessary* that I change $A_i$ to $W_a(i)$?

Comment: In you proof, as written, it appears that $g(x) = 1$ for all $x$, because for each $x$ there is at least one $i$ with $f_i(x) = 1$. The rest of the proof seem to have similar conceptual issues (for example, $D$ is collection of sets, not a collection of numbers - so what, then, is $D'$ supposed to be? But if $D$ is a set of numbers, so that $D'$ is a set of numbers, then it is impossible to have $D' \in D$). So the short answer seems to be "it isn't clear what you are asking, but the proof does not seem correct in any case".

Comment: Moreover, it is **true** that there is an r.e. enumeration of r.e. indices, say $(e_i)$, such that $W_{e_i}$ is computable for each $i$, and such every computable set is $W_{e_i}$ for some $i$. Namely, let $e_i$ be a program that enumerates $W_i$ so long as the enumeration is strictly increasing, and stops enumerating elements into $W_{e_i}$ any time the enumeration of $W_i$ is not strictly increasing. This, any proof that claims that no such sequence of indices exists must be flawed.

Comment: About $g(x)$ - I thought it was desirable: g will output 1 for x if x is in any one of the recursive sets in the enumeration, i.e. if *some* $f$ gives 1 on x, and undefined otherwise. About D: yes, it is a collection of sets, the recursive ones, assuming one *can* enumerate them all. I thought it was perfectly clear what D` was, assuming the complement is defined, which by hypothesis, if D's recursive, so must its complement (right?) and so complement of D must be defined. I don't know if I'm following you here; I appreciate your efforts above. Give me a couple days to think this through.